# How to recall first image taken by camera intent?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to have various images in my app taken by the user on google maps API v2.  All works fine fine, but cant seem to bring up the correct image when setting `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` only the last image taken by the camern a shows but not the first on.   So what i have done was to create an `onSaveInstanceState` with this code:

```
private static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "fileUri";
LatLng theLastImage;
```

and then:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(EXTRA_IMAGE, fileUri);
```

and then onRestore:

```
@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        theLastImage = (LatLng)savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXTRA_IMAGE);
```

and then in my `onInfoWindowClick` :

```
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
      theLastImage=point;

      googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
              Intent intent = new Intent();

              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              intent.putExtra("fileUri", theLastImage);
               Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + bitmap + fileUri);
                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            return;
          }
      });
```

But it still just showa the lataest image taken, no matter on which marker you tap on the map.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks